# Aplicar una función a todos los elementos de una Lista en Java

Tags: java, android

A menudo debo recorrer listas enteras para aplicar a cada elemento una función:

```
List<Markers> wayPoints;

int total = wayPoints.size();
for (int i=0;i<total;++i){
    wayPoints.get(i).setVisible(false);
}
```

Me pregunto si hay una forma más corta y eficiente para referirme a todos los elementos y aplicar la misma acción a ellos.

Comment: Hola WebServeis. Has probado alguna forma? Te dio fallos o problemas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías usar un for each, es más corto y no tendrías que declarar el total de iteraciones a realizar:

```
List<Markers> wayPoints;
for(Markers m : wayPoints){
   m.setVisible(false);
}
```

Si usas Java 8, puedes usar una expresión Lambda que será mucho más corta:

```
List<Markers> wayPoints;
wayPoints.forEach((u) -> u.setVisible(false));
```

Answer (score 3):

Una forma muy eficiente que ofrece Java para recorrerse los elementos de una colección es mediante el uso de bucles *for-each*:

```
List<Markers> wayPoints;

for(Markers m : wayPoints){ // Se traduce como.... para cada m de tipo Markers de la colección wayPoints
   m.setVisible(false)
}
```

Otra forma más avanzada a partir de Java 8, es el empleo de la programación funcional de Java mediante el uso de *lambdas* tal y como te ha explicado **Flowen**.

Answer (score 2):

Viene a ser lo mismo, utiliza un forEach también pero parece más limpio.

```
  List<Markers> wayPoints;
  wayPoints.forEach((u) -> u.setVisible(false));
```

Comment: Hola Flowen, mira [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tus respuestas. Lo importante de una respuesta es la explicacion y despues el codigo para representar lo explicado. Un saludo